# Dart "--no-sound-null-safety" flag not working

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I am trying to run a dart file without null safety using the command line.

The file is:

**sandbox.dart**

```
void main() {
    String a;
    print(a);
}
```

I then run the file using:

```
$ dart --no-sound-null-safety run sandbox.dart
```

This is described here:
https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

However, I still get the error:

```
Error: Non-nullable variable 'a' must be assigned before it can be used.
print(a);
```

I am using dart version;

```
Dart SDK version: 2.12.4 (stable) (Thu Apr 15 12:26:53 2021 +0200) on "windows_x64"
```

Why is it not working?

Note: It works by adding the version string at the top:

```
// @dart=2.9
```

But not the command line.

Comment: This seems a case where an issue on dart cli repo would be more helpful IMO. I also tried it quickly and can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter new versions no longer supporting "--no-sound-null-safety" flag [read release note](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/120936)

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand the [Unsound null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety) and how it works in different dart versions.

Dart provides null safety meaning values can't be null unless you allow them to be by using **?** so it becomes:

```
void main() {
    String? a;
    print(a);
}
```

This returns a null instead of the nun-nullable error.

Using language version 2.9 for a library that’s in a 2.12 package can reduce analysis errors (red squiggles) coming from unmigrated code. However, **unsound null safety** reduces the information the analyzer can use. For example, the analyzer might assume a parameter type is non-nullable, even though a 2.9 file might pass in a null value.

Answer (score 0):

You have two way to handle it.

1. You can Ignore it by  pasting --no-sound-null-safety command in Additional Run args( Android Studio Click on Drop Down on Top Middle with main.dart label and click on Edit Configuration paste --no-sound-null-safety command in additional run args).
2. (**Recommended**)
   You can accept it and enjoy the latest feature by upgrading sdk version in PubSpec.yml minimum Sdk for null safety must be  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0".
   Hope this will work for you